# How to connect 2 Databases with each other which are present on 2 Different Machines

Tags: php, mysql, database, replication

I have a website which is is connected to a local machine. both machines are Running and PHP applications with with same databases and tables and i want to update my Website's database when my Local Machine's database got Updated. 
How Can i do this ?

If your answer is REPLICATION then please explain me the whole procedure because i already tried ( Here I am using 2 Machines both are on localhost and both are working on Windows 8 ) that but it is not working.

I watch the several Tutorials on YouTube as well but nothing happens i don't know where is the problem because in those Tutorials it is working fine but on my machines it is not working at all....

Comment: Have you activated logging on your machines and have any additional info or error that you are running into?

Comment: first you should check that can you access website mysql server remotely. if yes then go for replication

Comment: @HiteshMundra I think REPLICATION is Command based technique where you can connect 2 Machine's Databases. But it is also a temporary solution means if one machine turned off the link will broke and we have to recreate the link manually. But i want permanent solution means if by chance system turned off and i restart the system the link between databases should be created automatically. because i don't want to create   link between these machines every time. .... Please tell me if there is any solution.

Comment: @ArshKaushal if am confused about data flow is unidirectional or bidirectional , means update of database is from website to local machine or local to website or both ways ?

Comment: @HiteshMundra i have a 2 machines [ M1 and M2 ] right. Now M1 is my Localhost machine which is not online but connected to internet and this machine will be placed in the market or offices like ATM machines are placed in the Banks (and Users will use that machines ) and on the other side M2 is  that Machines which is online means it is my website , ok both has databases of same type. And Users will use M1 machine and do there task and INSERT and MODIFY some data. So I want that if user use the M1 and Change or insert any data on M1 then databases of my website should be updated automatically

Answer (score 0):

If your M2 machine (website) is able to access the machine M1 (local), then you can set up master slave replication where master is M1 and the necessary condition is M2 can't used for insert update. If you want that M2 also takes part into insert update, then you set master-master replication.

else you can set up cron job at machine M1 which takes incremental backup of mysql server databases by read binary logs example all transactions of yesterday & restored to machine M2.